Proof for formula of sum of factors of $n$
For a given composite number $n=a^pb^qc^r \cdots$. Now the number of factors it has are ${(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)...}$ and the sum of all its factors are ${(a^0+a^1+...+a^p)(b^0+b^1+...+b^q)(c^0+c^1+...+c^r)...}$
I understand why the formula for the number of factors is this, but I couldn't find any proof of why the sum of factors is what it is. Could someone please explain? Thanks!

Given the factorization of $n$ into powers of primes, what can you say about it's factors? What are the primes in their factorization?

Every divisor can be written as $a^i \cdot b^j \cdot c^k \cdot ...$ where $i$ can go from $0$ up to $p$, $j$ can go from $0$ up to $q$, $k$ from $0$ up to $r$, ..., summing the whole thing is obvious.

@Dominique Yeahh... I see it now. Expanding the formula would give you every combination of ${a^i.b^j.c^k}$ Thanks a lot

This is something that one should really intuit.  Just try it with a few small examples, for example $2^3\times 3^2 \times 5^4$ and you should see immediately why this is true.  To come up with a formal and well crafted proof, it may be a bit difficult/tedious to come up with the right labeling of variable and special cases but this is one of the cases where I feel it is more important to intuit why it must be true than to be able to write a good essay of a proof.

Let $n = p_{1}^{a_1}p_{2}^{a_2} \cdots p_{r}^{a_r}$, where $a_i$'s are nonnegative integers and $p_i$'s are distinct primes. Now, if you observe that $p^a$ has $a+1$ many distinct factors, which are $1,p,p^2, \cdots,p^a$. Hence, the total number of factor of $n$ is $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{r}(a_r+1)$.
If you want to sum up the factors, that will be $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{j=0}^{a_i}p_{i}^{j} = \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{r}(1+p_i+p_i^2+ \cdots+ p_i^{a_{i}})$

A good way to break the situation "into pieces" is the fact that the function $s$ which associates to a positive natural number the sum of its positive divisior is "(restricted) multiplicative", i.e. if $m,n$ are relatively prime (to each other, seen as a pair with no common divisors), then we have
$$
s(m)s(n)=s(mn)\ .
$$
To see this restricted multiplicativity, notice that if $d$ divides $mn$, then collecting prime factors of $d$ that appear in $m$, and those that appear in $n$, and there is no collision, since no prime divides both $m,n$, then we have a unique representation $d=d_md_n$ with $d_m$ dividing $m$, and $d_n$ dividing $n$. The corresponding map $d\leftrightarrow (d_m,d_n)$ is thus bijective, so
$$
s(m)s(n)
=
\left(\sum_{d_m\mid m}d_m\right) \left(\sum_{d_n\mid n}d_n\right) =
\sum_{\substack{d_m\mid m\\d_n\mid n \\d=d_md_n}}d =
\sum_{d\mid mn}d =
s(mn)\ .
$$
Inductively, we need to know $s$ on a prime power $p^a$, which is
$s(p^a)=1+p+\dots+p^a$.
